# assignment of two Scala class instances

Tags: scala, class, pointers

```
class Counter {
  var counter: Int = 0
  def increaseCounter(): Unit =
    counter = counter + 1
}

var counter1 = new Counter
var counter2 = new Counter

counter1 = counter2

counter1.increaseCounter()
counter2.counter // => 1
```

I do not really understand why the counter of counter2 is changed even though I only changed the counter of counter1. Are Scala class instances just pointers and in this case counter1 and counter2 are pointing to the same object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala *variables* are just pointers, so this:

```
counter1 = counter2
```

makes both `counter1` and `counter2` point to the same instance.

This kind of hidden dependency is why you should avoid `var` as much as possible and always create new objects rather than modifying existing objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just like in Java. This you did is a shallow copy. If you want to assign the value of one be copied to the other you need a deep copy. You need
counter1.counter = counter2.counter